# Getting data from dynamic loading Linear Layout

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, selendroid

I am having a many Linear Layout that are same in layout. Here is hierarchy.

[image]

Every entry is like this: that is like LinearLayout {product_list} [0,202][480,455]

[image]

Now as I scroll down, it loads dynamically and goes till all results end.

So my first question is how to do this using Appium

I am having this class with me :

```
public class AllProductsCategoryPage extends BasePage{
    public AllProductsCategoryPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }
    public void getData() throws InterruptedException {
             List<String> prices;
    }
}
```

Here I want list of all the prices. The price value in all layouts is being com.myapp.android:id/product_list_product_item_price.

Please help to approach this problem.

The outer Framelayout is com.myapp.android:id/contentFragment

NOTE : On a current screen almost three Linear Layouts can be visible. So can we make use of it ? And then make use of code something like this :

```
public void scrollPageUp() {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    HashMap<String, Double> swipeObject = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    swipeObject.put("startX", 0.50);
    swipeObject.put("startY", 0.95);
    swipeObject.put("endX", 0.50);
    swipeObject.put("endY", 0.01);
    swipeObject.put("duration", 3.0);
    js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", swipeObject);
}
```

Comment: Sorry unable to understand your entire question.

Comment: @Gaurav I am having a List kind of Layout, when I scroll down more Linear Layouts come. So I want to have a List of values from all these Linear Layouts

Comment: @Gaurav Are you able to get it now ? Please help